# Vim file explorer - jump to file by letter

Tags: netrw, filesystem

[In windows file explorer, if you hit a letter like R, you get to a file/folder beginning with R.](https://superuser.com/questions/1724254/in-windows-file-explorer-how-to-quickly-jump-to-file-based-on-more-than-one-let)

Especially in directories with many files this is super convenient.

Does one of the Vim file explorers support this? Out of the box or with heavy configuring?

Any other Unix console mode file browser?

Answer (score 2):

Any Vim "file manager" is based upon "normal" Vim buffer/window functionality. So pressing "slash" and typing some regex (incl. literal "foobar") should work just as it does everywhere else. This is why one should learn Vim, not "netrw" or "help window" and such.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is not overly convenient, on a german keybord this is /^<space>R

Comment: You can make a mapping for this @weberjn; for example `nnoremap ! /^<Space>`. Then you can press `!` and start typing your search pattern (you can make this more advanced/complex if you want, but simple is usually best). Or override the `/` to insert the `^` and space automatically: `nnoremap / /^<Space>`. You can use a `filetype netrw` autocmd to only apply this for NetRW buffers.

Comment: @weberjn "Slash" is standard key used everywhere in Vim to search through text. If you have problems with pressing standard Vim keys you need to revise your keyboard/keymap/mappings etc.

Comment: @Matt its the caret, it needs a space to appear (or an a for â)

Comment: @weberjn Try it without the caret and space, I search all the time in Vim and don't even know where the caret is on my keyboard.